# SimpleDateFormat adding 7 hours?

Tags: java, date, time

I'm trying to do a simple subtraction of dates and getting odd results. For some reason when I format it with SimpleDateFormat, there are 7 extra hours difference.

```
package timedemo;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Timedemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date start = new Date(); // time right now
        Date stop = new Date();

        long startTime = start.getTime()-1000; // introduce a second of skew
        long stopTime = stop.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

        // First one shows up prior to 1970 epoch. Okay, except for 5 hour variance.
        // Probably a timezone thing, as I'm in EST (-5).
        System.out.println("New date is "+new Date(stopTime - startTime)); 
        System.out.println("Raw Start is "+startTime); // fine
        System.out.println("Raw Stop is  "+stopTime); // fine
        System.out.println("Raw Difference is "+(stopTime-startTime));
        System.out.println("Formatted Start is "+sdf.format(startTime));
        System.out.println("Formatted Stop is  "+sdf.format(stopTime));
        System.out.println("Formatted Difference is "+sdf.format(stopTime-startTime));

    }

}
```

And the results are:

```
New date is Wed Dec 31 19:00:01 EST 1969
Raw Start is 1418397344360
Raw Stop is  1418397345360
Raw Difference is 1000
Formatted Start is 10:15:44
Formatted Stop is  10:15:45
Formatted Difference is 07:00:01
```

- I had thought it was a timezone thing, but I'm in EST (-5), not MST (-7).
- I would suspect Daylight Savings, but it's 7 hours, not 1.
- 12/24 hour difference? 12-7=5 which is my timezone offset... not sure what to make of it though.
- Kind of out of ideas at this point.

Why the seven hour shift on the last line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: @BasilBourque Their question was "how do I do XYZ?" Mine was "why does this output look weird?" The answer is the same, but the question itself is different. I imagine folks who make the same silly mistake I did will have an easier time finding an answer if this one persists. But either way, no worries. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "12-7 = 5" is definitely related to the problem... or more accurately, it's "12-5=7", i.e. 5 hours before midnight is 7pm. You'll see that if you format it as a full date/time:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Heck, you can see that in your first line: "Wed Dec 31 19:00:01 EST 1969" - that 19:00 is 7pm, which you're formatting using `hh` as `07`.

Fundamentally, the problem is that you're trying to treat a *difference* in time as if it's a *point* in time. I would very strongly urge you not to do that. If you *absolutely* want to do that (and the difference will always be non-negative but less than 24 hours), then you should set the time zone on `SimpleDateFormat` to UTC, and use `HH` instead of `hh`. But it would be better to use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) or `java.time` from Java 8 which can represent a `Duration`, i.e. the difference between two points in time. `Date` is simply not an appropriate data type for that.

Comment: Duration is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Jon.